# Play frame generated war on jetty Perm gen issue

Tags: java, playframework, jetty

I have a Play application and I want to run that on a jetty server.
I generated a war out of the app using Play's buit in war generation;
play war (app) -o (output.war)

When I imported the generated war to Jetty's webapps and run the application;
**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space**

I googled around to find a solution but the available solution to increase the perm gen size and jvm arguments to for class unload all does not work.

I tired to analyze the prem zen size size using Plumbr but it does not generate the report.

Finally i used java's built in heap analyzer;
jmap -permstat

29928 intern Strings occupying 3174488 bytes.
class_loader    classes bytes   parent_loader   alive?  type

2764    15979584          null          live

total = 1       2764    15979584            N/A         alive=1, dead=0     N/A

This was the stats after jvm starting throwing prem gen error. The class loader size and static strings is quite less, less than 64 mb (I have increased the prem zen size to 1gb even same error)

Please suggest as I am not able to find the route cause of the issue.

Comment: You should put more infos about versions, we are not a operators of glass ball

Answer (score 0):

1. Start your application with "-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" jvm option
2. When and if you get OOM again, JVM will generate an heap dump file.
3. Open it with [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)
4. Let it generate a report for you